# Is Split Task functionality available in React Version of Dhtmlx Gantt Chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

The problem i am facing is displaying more than one task in a same row.
But the default structure of Gantt Chart is to show task in individual rows infront of task name. We have customize the structure and replaced task names ( left Columns of the Gantt Chart ) with the workers name. Tasks assigned to each Worker should displayed in the same row as the the worker name.

There is a functionality available in Js version of Gantt chart but not sure about the react version of it. In js one can access the instance of gantt chart and but in react you have to do everything with help of props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, split tasks functionality in React version of Dhtmlx Gantt chart is not available.

This functionality is available in the PRO version of JS dhtmlxGantt https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__split_tasks.html. JS dhtmlxGantt can be used in react app. To do this, you need to write a wrapper component.

Here is a demo and tutorial on how to do it:
https://github.com/DHTMLX/react-gantt-demo
https://dhtmlx.com/blog/create-react-gantt-chart-component-dhtmlxgantt/

Here is the demo, with JS dhtmlxGantt split tasks in react app:
https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/22969d8959ddb7651919594cd28848fd/gantt-react+split.zip.